# HTML in field break content of mysql query

Tags: mysql, html

I have a query in mysql which list posts and its fields.

```
SELECT Post.Id as 'Post ID', Post.`Subject` as 'Post Subject',
        (SELECT PostField.`Value` FROM PostField WHERE Template_id=816 AND PostField.Post_id=Post.Id) AS 'Summary.',
        (SELECT PostField.`Value` FROM PostField WHERE Template_id=816 AND PostField.Post_id=Post.Id) AS 'Scenario',
        (SELECT PostField.`Value` FROM PostField WHERE Template_id=817 AND PostField.Post_id=Post.Id) AS 'Budget'
FROM Post
WHERE Post.Category_id = 25;
```

My problem is PostField.Value has html content so when I run query and export to excel just first line occur.
How can remove html. I want to export to excel.

Comment: Launch your copy of Excel and type `<strong>`. Does anything break?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove HTML, use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags). But You don't have to. You need to properly escape your output. If you are using CSV format for example, enclose content in quotes and use [fput_csv](http://php.net/fput_csv) function

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

`SELECT REPLACE(PostField.Value, (PostField.Value REGEXP '<.*?>'), '');`